# WidgetPad is opensource but can't find the source code

Tags: html

As it is said here
http://www.iphoneworld.ca/news/2009/09/16/widgetpad-for-open-source-iphone-apps/

but where is the source code ?

Answer (score 1):

[Here is its official page](http://widgetpad.com/)